# Uniqueness/existence of weak solution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Provide a weak formulation for the following boundary value problem
$$
-\Delta u=f, \quad \text { in } \Omega, \quad \text { and }\left.\quad u\right|_{\partial \Omega}=0 \space \space \space \space \space 
\space (1)
$$
Prove that for any $f \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ there exists a unique weak solution of (1).

**My attempt:**

$$
\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}=\int \nabla u \cdot \nabla u=\int f u \leq\|f\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq C_{\epsilon}\|f\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}+\epsilon\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2} .
$$
Using the Poincare inequality for $u:\|u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$ and taking $\epsilon$ sufficiently small we have
$$
\|\nabla u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)} .
$$
So, assuming there are two weak solutions $u, v \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, consider $w=u-v$ which solves $\Delta w=0$ with $w=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Our above estimate establishes that $w \equiv 0$ and so $u=v$.

I know this proves uniqueness, but how can I prove *existence*?

Can anyone show how I can apply Lax-Milgram here?

Comment: I don't know how to apply it here though

Comment: Please do not delete questions after you have received an answer. This is a little rude to the person who spent time trying to help you.

Comment: This does not answer my question in totality. If I don't delete I cannot repost, and no one will answer the question in totality.

Comment: That is not how the site works. As far as I can see, you have not even told Surb that you think the current answer is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

The weak form of your equation is given by
$$-\int_\Omega \nabla \varphi \cdot \nabla u=\int_\Omega f\varphi ,\quad \varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega )$$
If you set $$B(u,\varphi ):=-\int_\Omega \nabla \varphi \cdot \nabla u\quad \text{and}\quad L(\varphi ):=\int_\Omega f\varphi. $$
The existence of a weak solution of your problem is equivalent than proving the existence of $u\in H_0^1(\Omega )$ s.t. $$B(u,\varphi )=L(\varphi ),$$
for all $\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega )$.

Notice that by [Riesz-representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#Statement), there is a unique $\hat f\in H_0^1(\Omega )$ s.t. $$L(\varphi )=\left<\hat f,\varphi \right>_{H_0^1(\Omega )},$$
for all $\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega )$. Now, existence of $u\in H_0^1(\Omega )$ s.t. $$B(u,\varphi )=\left<\hat f,\varphi \right>_{H_0^1(\Omega )},$$
for all $\varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega )$
follows from [Lax-Milgram Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lions%E2%80%93Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem).

---

What remains to prove to be able to use Lax-Milgram Theorem is that $L$ is linear and continuous, and that $B$ is bilinear, continuous and coercive, i.e. that there is $C>0$ s.t. $|B(v,v)|\geq C\|v\|_{H_0^1(\Omega )}$ for all $v\in H_0^1(\Omega )$.